# Inter-app communication in iOS using URL scheme

Tags: ios, swift, url, fatal-error

I have two test apps: App1 & App2.

App1 takes String from the text field and triggers method:

```
@IBAction func openApp(sender: AnyObject) { 
    let url1 = ("app2://com.application.started?displayText="+textToSend.text!)
    let url2 = url1.stringByAddingPercentEncodingWithAllowedCharacters(NSCharacterSet.URLQueryAllowedCharacterSet())
    UIApplication.sharedApplication().openURL(NSURL(string: url2!)!)
}
```

Which actually opens App2 which has only label which should change to the text sent through the url, code is within AppDelegate.swift:

```
func application(app: UIApplication, openURL url: NSURL, options: [String : AnyObject]) -> Bool {
    let url = url.standardizedURL
    let query = url?.query
    ViewController().labelToDisplayResult.text = query
    return true;
}
```

Unfortunately the line where I am trying to pass result of the URL to the actual label is giving me this error:

```
EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION (CODE=EXC_I386_INVOP SUBCODE=0x0)
```

However I have all the data in the App2 for sure as I can see their values in debugger:

```
url NSURL   "app2://com.application.started?displayText=564315712437124375" 0x00007fa4e3426320
query   String? "displayText=564315712437124375"
```

Any idea why I am getting this error?

Thanks...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your error

```
ViewController().labelToDisplayResult.text = query
```

`ViewController()` Create a new instance of `ViewController`,not the one loaded from storyboard.I guess `labelToDisplayResult` is an outlet, so it is nil,so you get `EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION (CODE=EXC_I386_INVOP SUBCODE=0x0)`

This is what I usually do to handle openURL scheme,need to think about two states:

1. Target App is launched before,so when open url happen,the target app is in background or inactive state
2. Target App is not launched,so when open url happen,the target app is not running at all

In Appdelegate

```
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {
var openUrl:NSURL? //This is used when to save state when App is not running before the url trigered
var window: UIWindow?


func application(app: UIApplication, openURL url: NSURL, options: [String : AnyObject]) -> Bool {
    let url = url.standardizedURL
    NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().postNotificationName("HANDLEOPENURL", object:url!)
    self.openUrl = url
    return true;
}

func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool {

    return true
}
}
```

Then in the ViewController handle openURL

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

@IBOutlet weak var testLabel: UILabel!
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
     NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: "handleOpenURL:", name:"HANDLEOPENURL", object: nil)
    let delegate = UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as? AppDelegate
    if let url = delegate?.openUrl{
       testLabel.text = url.description 
        delegate?.openUrl = nil 
    }
}
func handleOpenURL(notification:NSNotification){
    if let url = notification.object as? NSURL{
        testLabel.text = url.description
    }
}
deinit{
    NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().removeObserver(self, name: "HANDLEOPENURL", object:nil)
}

}
```

Comment: Thank you, I am very new to any iOS and Swift development, how can I get the value form the AppDelegate to the ViewController if I want to display value passed through the URL scheme?

Comment: This throws error, but thank you anyway, very good point that I need to think about both states.

Comment: Sorry my bad, its not throwing error, its actually working like a charm... Had there mistake of my own. Thank you very much!

Comment: could you please explain to me or add some comments on NSNotificationCenter part? Thank you